# Selected event not raised for ObjectDatasource when enable-caching is true

Tags: caching, count, record, objectdatasource

I've a Gridview control using an ODS(ObjectDataSource) to fetch data. For the best performance and efficiency, I've turned-off the view state of Gridview (i.e. EnableViewstate = "false".

And I've also enabled caching in the associated Objectdatasource. This eliminates as much as 50-60% performance optimization because it eliminates the DB round-trip .. courtesy ODS Caching.

So, after this I got stuck into the famous "ODS sorting" issue but I managed to invent a tricky solution for it and its working fine:

> [Optimize Pagination & Sorting with ObjectDataSource having EnableCaching = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255269/optimize-pagination-sorting-with-objectdatasource-having-enablecaching-true)

Next pagination, it is also working fine. Now, I need to display "Total records: X" at the top of the Gridview. Well, I deployed the following method:

```
protected void ods_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.ReturnValue != null && e.ReturnValue.GetType() == typeof(int))
                base.setTotalLabel(lblTotal, e.ReturnValue);
        }
```

Don't confuse - base.setTotalLabel is my own method to set the label text with the count. This is also working fine but the issue is that -

> Whenever, the ODS fetches data from
>   its Cache it won't trigger the
>   ODS_Selecting or ODS_Select events.
>   They are simply "by-passed" because it
>   takes data from cache. This is when I
>   fail to refresh the Total records
>   count!

I hope I've explained my problem good, this is tricky. I'm ready to do any trick or dirty coding for this because I want to maintain the ODS-caching and I can't rollback changes just because of a few incidental "mis-updates".

Pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me I set the CacheKeyDependency and I explicitly set it to a new value whenever I want to refresh. I pass &refresh=1 in querystring if I want to explicitly refresh.

In .aspx -

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsOrg" runat="server" SelectMethod="SearchOrg" ... EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="60" CacheKeyDependency="key1">
```

In code behind -

```
public const string argRefresh = "refresh=1";
public void CheckExpiredCacheKey(string ckey)
{
 if (Cache[ckey] == null) 
  Cache[ckey] = new object(); //Set Cache key which will b used to manually expire ODS cache     

if (!IsPostBack && Request.QueryString["refresh"] == "1")//check refresh flag
 {
    //Cache.Remove(ckey);//NOT NEEDED: use the following instead
    Cache[ckey] = new object();// Needed otherwise it'll call Grid-populate twice
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the **exact** same problem?

A solution I have been doing is to call the select count method again (via BLL) in the gridview databinding method and storing this in a viewstate var then using it to display the number of records. But this leads to two things:

- another call to the DB count sp (defeats caching purpose)
- conflict of presentation i.e. number of cached records displayed may not match the actual number(which is up-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by storing the record count in a session variable during the selected event:

```
protected void odsSearchResults_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable resultsTable = e.ReturnValue as DataTable;
        if (resultsTable == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Session["ResultCount"] = resultsTable.Rows.Count;
        lblRecordCount.Text = resultsTable.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Then in Page_Load I display the record count if the session var is not null:

```
if(Session["ResultCount"] != null)
{
    lblRecordCount.Text = Session["ResultCount"].ToString();
}
```

Now lblRecordCount will show the record count if the data comes from the cache or not