# ods generic caching and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

First, I'd like to say, Argh!!

[Picking off where this thread left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316959/selected-event-not-raised-for-objectdatasource-when-enable-caching-is-true)

Basically the thread is about not being able to sort generic list with caching enabled. I've tried a combination of replies but no luck. Seems like I'm very close but yet so far...

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //What goes in this area?
    CheckExpiredCacheKey(argRefresh);
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["sortBy"].DefaultValue = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");                     
    e.Cancel = true;
}

public void CheckExpiredCacheKey(string ckey)
{
    if (Cache[ckey] == null)
        Cache[ckey] = new object(); //Set Cache key which will b used to manually expire ODS cache     

    if (!IsPostBack && Request.QueryString["refresh"] == "1")//check refresh flag
    {
        //Cache.Remove(ckey);//NOT NEEDED: use the following instead
        Cache[ckey] = new object();// Needed otherwise it'll call Grid-populate twice
    }
}
```

Here's the Select method where the sortBy string is always blank when trying this way of sorting generic list and caching?

```
[DataObject(true)]
public class BusinessLogic
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public static List<Customer> GetCustomers(int financeId, int startIndex, int pageSize, string sortBy)
    {
        return DataAccess.GetCustomers(financeId, startIndex, pageSize, sortBy);
    }
```